# functional analysis - null space (homework)

Tags: functional-analysis

I meet a problem in a textbook and have thought for a long time but still cannot solve it out.

Let $X$ be a normed linear space, $f,g\in X^{'}$. $N(f)\subset X$ denotes the null space of $f$. If $N(f)=N(g)$, prove that there exists $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, such that $f=\alpha g$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x_0)=$1, then $g(x_0)\neq 0$. You can show that $g=g(x_0)f$. If there is no $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=1$, then $f=g=0$.